# Tab is not focus on link

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, safari, focus

I'm using Bootstrap to create link. while using that the link render as `<a href="#"><span> link </span></a>`.

Actually It focused in firefox without border using tab key, but not in safari.

**Actually anchor tag is not focused in safari by using tab key**

**But If I use like following, it's working..**

`<a href="#"><span tabindex='1'> link </span></a>`.
**I cannot find solution for this .. I am using safari version 5.1.7. I want to use without tab index.**

Comment: Why do you need the `<span>` here?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: In the first one you don't close the `<a>` tag.  Just saying.

Comment: please elaborate your issue. are you referring to the tabindex and css focus color?

Comment: I've edited my query. Please look through it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be cause of anchor is not aligned properly in DOM. `span` tag width and height will be in set in proper but the `span` properties are not set to anchor.

Try to give `float left` for anchor. It may work

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing to do with the HTML but is designed this way by Safari.

Check the settings in Safari `Advanced > Universal Access` check the box with `Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage`. Then Safari will show the same behavior as other browsers.

Comment: I did that. But it's not working for <a href="#"><span> </span> </a> .
but working for <a href="#"></a>

Comment: @Vijay Weird. Does it work on this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9k8uT/show/ ? Which version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Yes .. I don't know what's the problem.. It's working for what you've given .. But not for me..

Comment: It's like <h2><a href="#"><span> </span> </a> </h2> in my application

Comment: Thank you for your valuable effort. I've edited my question. Please look through it.

Comment: @MaxK, is there a similar setting for Firefox?